# homework and overloading in java

Tags: java, overloading

Ok so this is my homework assignment, and I am having a heck of a time figuring out how to correctly use overloading to allow for a certain number of terms to print out.

"Create a class that contains a method that accepts an integer from the user to display the next 5 terms in the following pattern: (n-7) * 3.

So, if the user enters 5, the output should be:

-6

-39

-138

-435

-1326

Add an overloaded method so the user can enter how many termss they want to print out in a pattern:

So, the user would enter 5 as the starting number and 3 as the number of terms to print out in the pattern.

The output would be:

-6

-39

-435

Add different method that displays the formula and provides calculation to the formula: (should get starting number from user input) and prints out the next 5 terms.

(5-7) * 3 = -6

(-6-7) * 3= -39

(-39-7) * 3 = -435

Add an overloaded method that displays the formula and the calculation to the formula and takes in how many times it should print: (should get from user input).

For example: User enters 5 as the starting number and print out 4 times.

(5-7) * 3 = -6

(-6-7) * 3= -39

(-39-7) * 3 = -435

(-435-7) * 3 = -1326

Specifics:

You have a separate class that contains all your methods.
You should have 4 methods in this class.
Your main should call these four methods getting user input where appropriate.
 "

I'm not asking for anyone to do this for me, I just would appreciate a steer in the right direction.
At the moment trying to collect the number of terms wanted by the user in the main class then pass it to the Numberpattern class and then from their have the program determine which Calc method to use is not working.

Comment: AH, homework. 'tis like medicine.. if u only knew

Comment: post what you have so far

Comment: I assume you already have the first part down ... instead of running over the loop 5 times, have it run `n` times and have `n` be a parameter. Then you can have an overloaded function which doesn't take `n` as a parameter, and instead calls your original function with a parameter of 5.

Answer (score 2):

Okay i feel dirty for doing your homework for you but i'll get you started

the first method is

```
public void printPattern(int n){
    int prevAnswer = n; 
    for(int i =0; i < 5; i ++){
        int newAnswer = (prevAnswer - 7) * 3;    
        System.out.println(newAnswer);
        prevAnswer = newAnswer;
    }
}
```

The first overload is

```
public void printPattern(int n, int c){ //this is the overload
    public void printPattern(int n){
    int prevAnswer = n; 
    for(int i =0; i < c; i ++){ // i < c to print that many numbers in the sequence
        int newAnswer = (prevAnswer - 7) * 3;    
        System.out.println(newAnswer);
        prevAnswer = newAnswer;
    }
}
```

To Overload a method simply provide different parameters and write the extended new functionality

Comment: Ahh ok that makes a lot more sense. I wasn't looping it and was trying to individually assign each variable to a value. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Your welcome if your stuck on the other ones sing out

Answer (score 0):

By overloading a method, you are using the same methods with different parameter lists. This allows the program to decide which method is best to be used with only one call of that method name.

It looks like your first method would have a loop of a fixed number and only one parameter (n). Your second method will have the same name, but now allow for two parameters - the (n) and the number of times to loop.

public static void nextTerms (int n) {
   Your fixed count loop and print out of n code...
}

public static void nextTerms (int n, int loopCount) {
   Your changeable loopCount count loop and print out of n code...
}

To run that nextTerms method, your main Class could either call:

nextTerms(5);

or

nextTerms(5, 3);

The program will then decide which of the two nextTerms methods are appropriate.

For more information, I suggest - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Cheers!
Chris

Comment: That makes sense. I wasn't using a loop which was where I was getting hung up. Thank you.